# Navigation to fourth view is not showing back button in storyboard app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, storyboard

I am implementing a iPhone app in **iOS 6** using **storyboard**. Below is the structure of the views in storyboard:
[image]

```
        1                    2                   3                4
```

I have connected push event from 3rd view to the 4th one. It successfully navigate to 4th in the image but my problem is it is not showing back button. So I can't bring it back to 3rd view. navigation from 2nd view to 3rd view is fine.

Can anyone guide me what I am missing here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's nothing in what you describe that should cause this problem. When you go to the 4th view do you see the navigation bar?

Comment: the 4th .. is not "pushing" :)

Answer (score 0):

```
     first check how many controller are navigated
      NSArray *array1 = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
       nslog(@"%@",array1);

     then
     u can try this one
      [self.navigationController popToViewController:[array1 objectAtIndex:3] animated:YES];
```